# pass my php variables to a bootstrap modal not working

Tags: bootstrap-modal

in my page

```
foreach ($json->items as $sam) {
    $link= $sam->id->videoId;
    echo''.$link.'';
    //its showing last 5 youtube video id ok.. i set every video id witha button for modal

     echo'<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PlayModal" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">Play</button>';
}
```

but when im trying to open a model by box in new winddow pop up there only show 1st video ID. modal not getting '.$link.' valu in popup window. modal code puting same page blew finish {}

```
echo'<div class="modal inmodal" id="PlayModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>'.$name.'</p>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
     </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code given, even the first video should not play.

it is not printing the value of LINK inside the button, so it will not work.
Unless you have a JAVASCRIPT code observing the click and playing the video on click.

You can create the HTML code first manually containing the 5 video ID, and each video should have a button (according to your description), when clicked it will open the modal.

once that is done, you will be able to use php for each to properly echo the html code.

alternatively, the videos are in HTML list, and javascript will handle the event click, reading the video ID and passing to the player in the modal.

in either case, you need to understand the HTML structure first.

Comment: if i use <a hrfe="$link">button</a> then it pass valu ?

Comment: that's one way. but it will not play the video, instead, it will open a new page (or tab).

see the demo for two buttons, large and small:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

each button opens a different modal.
in your case, each button will need a player.


or, you can rely on jquery to pass the id. example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-related-target